# What slider does NOS DRINKS use?

Tags: css, wordpress, slider

How do I create a slider [like this](http://www.drinknos.com/)  - Under the "GO HUNTING FOR A NOS"

What slider do i need, for it to work in the same way.

Comment: SO is not a place to find tutorials or ides, kindly google it. :)

Comment: They seem to be using a proprietary developed carousel. However simply search for jQuery carousel and you will find many. Check out this one for example (scroll down to "Center Mode"): http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](http://www.drinknos.com/wp-content/themes/drinknos/inc/script/app/component/carousel.js) - this is the source code for their carousel. It looks like they may be using [carousel.js](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_carousel.asp) or a modified version of it.

You can use their code as a source for your own system or find another plugin - someone already mentioned [slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) but [Cycle2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/) and [Flickity](http://flickity.metafizzy.co/) are good ones too. Play around and see what one works best for you.